# Why crashed? c++ reference to a static variable within a function gets invalid

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a reference which points to another object inside a static function. Like the following pseudo code. When I call B->foo(), it crashed, because B.aa is not valid reference. Why? Could it be pointing to some garbage memory? If I want to protect around the crashed line aa.func(), what can I do with this aa reference?

```
Class A {
public:
    void func() {}
};

A& GetClassA()
{
    static A* ptr = new A();
    return &ptr;
}

Class B {
    A& aa;
    B(): aa(GetClassA()) {}
    void foo() {
        aa.func();          // crashed here.
    }
}

int main()
{
    // B is created
    B* b = new B();
    // some code here...
    ...
    // now access B->aa.func()
    B->foo();  // crashed inside B->foo(), why ?
}
```

Comment: You return a reference to a temporary object in your `GetClassA()` function. Edit: oh wait, it's even worse, it's not a reference to a temporary object, but a reference to a pointer, what

Comment: I really hope you have compiler warnings enabled and that you're not ignoring these warnings ?

Comment: Sorry, that should be &ptr. I mistyped the return value. In the code, it is &ptr. Why does it crash?

Answer (score 3):

Well you have numerous syntax and semantics errors in your code, but perhaps the offender you're looking for is:

```
A& GetClassA()
{ 
    static A* ptr = new A();
    return &ptr;
}
```

Your function signature says it should return an `A&`, but it returns an `A**`. It should be:

```
A& GetClassA()
{ 
    static A* ptr = new A();
    return *ptr;
}
```

Comment: oh, sorry, it did return &ptr. I am going to edit the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I think something's wrong here,

```
A& GetClassA()
{ 
    static A* ptr = new A();
    return &ptr;
}
```

you are creating `new A()`, having a pointer to it, and then you return an address of a pointer (double pointer) but return type of this method is `A&`, shouldn't it be `A**` ? or maybe you want to `return *ptr;` ?

Comment: Yes. It returns &ptr. Sorry.